# Access the selected item from Workflow within a Sandboxed solution

Tags: workflow, sandbox-solution

I am a workflow newbie so please forgive me if this is a naive question, but is there a way to programmatically get a reference to the selected item(s) of the list that initiated the workflow, in a sandboxed solution?

I'd like to be able to preform actions on each list item who's checkbox is selected when the user executes a workflow. Seems like this should be easy, though I cannot find a straight forward was of accomplishing this, I feel like I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If inside the workflow you can use [SPWorkflow.ParentList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflow.parentlist)

If not in the workflow then you need to implement an [SPWorkflowEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556021) in [SPWorkflowEventReceiver.WorkflowStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.workflowstarted) you can use `properties.ActivationProperties.Item`